# Problem connectivity issue to port 54663 (bamboo tcp port)

Tags: docker, tcp, port, bamboo

I've installed bamboo with docker-compose, here is the definition:

```
...
  bamboo:
    image: atlassian/bamboo-server
    container_name: bamboo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./bamboo:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
      - 54663:54663
...
```

The connectivity of port 8085 is ok and I receive this output by `nmap`:

```
# nmap 91.98.96.204 -p8085
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-05 15:28 UTC
Nmap scan report for mail.***.com (**.***.**.***)
Host is up (0.13s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8085/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.32 seconds
```

But I have problem with 54663.

```
# nmap 91.98.96.204 -p54663
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-07-05 15:40 UTC
Nmap scan report for mail.***.com (**.***.**.***)
Host is up (0.13s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE
54663/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.33 seconds
```

I'm using ufw and rules are correctly defined:

```
# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8085/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
54663/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
...
8085/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
54663/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
...
```

listening status of port 54663 in the server is ok:

```
# netstat -an | grep 54663
tcp6       0      0 :::54663                :::*                    LISTEN
```

and this is my iptables diff before and after packet transmission:

```
# diff Sample1 Sample2
1c1
< Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 9 packets, 360 bytes)
---
> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 400 bytes)
6,8c6,8
<  180K 9856K ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
<  180K 9856K ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
<  180K 9856K ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
---
>  180K 9857K ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>  180K 9857K ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>  180K 9857K ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
65c65
< 5672K  340M ACCEPT     all  --  br-83aa54bad204 br-83aa54bad204  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
---
> 5673K  340M ACCEPT     all  --  br-83aa54bad204 br-83aa54bad204  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
127,128c127,128
< 68748 3877K ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-83aa54bad204 br-83aa54bad204  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.26          tcp dpt:80
<    15   676 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-0f9a0f7345b4 br-0f9a0f7345b4  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.48.2         tcp dpt:54663
---
> 68755 3877K ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-83aa54bad204 br-83aa54bad204  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.26          tcp dpt:80
>    16   720 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-0f9a0f7345b4 br-0f9a0f7345b4  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.48.2         tcp dpt:54663
190c190
< 86160   12M ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
---
> 86162   12M ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
229c229
< 39016 2581K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
---
> 39017 2581K ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
265c265
< 96024   13M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
---
> 96026   13M RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who came into this post, I found my solution:

The Broker URL must be set to the 0.0.0.0:54663, in the `settings > system > general cofiguration`

[image]